# For two dataframes df and logicaldf of the same size, what does the command df[logicaldf, ] execute in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I recently came across `df[logicaldf,]` command and was really confused as I have only seen the `df[x,]` format where x is a column in the `dataframe`. Here is an example chunk when I ran the code in R:

```
> c1 <- c(11, 2, 3, 4, 53)
> c2 <- c(9, 3, 5, 5, 2)
> c3 <- c(1, 10, 3, 2, 2)
> foo <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3)
 
> foo5 <- foo > 5
> head(foo5)
        c1    c2    c3
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

> table(rowSums(foo5))
0 1 2 
2 2 1 

> foo[foo5, ]
     c1 c2 c3
1    11  9  1
5    53  2  2
NA   NA NA NA
NA.1 NA NA NA
```

Could someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit the comma, then you would just extract the elements where `foo5==TRUE`:

```
foo[foo5]
## 11 53  9 10
```

However, because you include the comma, `foo5` is converted to matrix and then to a vector.  Thus inside of the brackets `foo5` becomes:

```
as.vector(as.matrix(foo5))
## TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Now, the 4 `TRUE`s occur in positions 1, 5, 6, and 12.  So your subset command (`foo[foo5,]`) is trying to grab rows 1, 5, 6, and 12 from `foo`.  Thus, the result is rows 1 and 5, and two rows of `NA`s because `foo` doesn't have rows 6 and 12.

Notice we can replicate your result like so:

```
foo[c(1,5,6,12), ]
 ##      c1 c2 c3
 ## 1    11  9  1
 ## 5    53  2  2
 ## NA   NA NA NA
 ## NA.1 NA NA NA
```